# Overriding instantiate using JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, oop

What code should I put in the override constructor at the last part of the program? It's the one with the asterisk...

```
public class Author {
    private int authorId;
    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;

    public Author(int authorId,String lastName,String firstName){
        this.authorId = authorId;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }


    public int getAuthorId() {
        return authorId;
    }

    public void setAuthorId(int authorId) {
        this.authorId = authorId;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
}
```

MAIN METHOD

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Catalogue {

    static int choice;
    static int task;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Choices\n\n1. Author\n2.Book\n3.Borrower");
        choice = scan.nextInt();

        switch(choice){

        case 1:
        {
            Author author = new Author(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Auhtor ID")),
                    (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Author Last Name")),
                    (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Author First Name")));
        }
        case 2:
        {
            Book book = new Book(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Book ID")),
                    (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Title")),
                    (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter ISBN")));
        }
        case 3:
        {
            Borrower borrower = new Borrower(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Student ID")),
                    (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Last Name")),
                    (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter First Name")));
        }
        default:{
            System.out.println("Invalid Input");
        }
        }

        System.out.println("Enter TASK \n\n1. Auhtor\n2.Book\n3.Borrower");
        System.out.println("Enter Choices\n\n1. Auhtor\n2.Book\n3.Borrower");
        task = scan.nextInt();
    if(task == 1){
            Author author = new Author(********);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Author ID:  " + author.getAuthorId());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Author Last Name:  " + author.getLastName());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Author First Name:  " + author.getFirstName());
    }
    else if(task == 2){
        Book book = new Book(**************);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Author ID:  " + book.getBookId());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Author Last Name:  " + book.getTitle());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Author First Name:  " + book.getIsbn());
    }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I need a better explanation to help you. What you want to achieve?

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve] - I'm sure you don't need over 130 lines to demonstrate the problem. Next note that constructors are never overridden, which makes it harder to understand what you're after...